# converting rows into column in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Hi i want to convert column into rows. Can anyone please tell me how can i do it.

Input:-

```
id name
10 shruti
20 Wipro
```

Output should be

```
id   10     20
name shruti wipro
```

Please note there can be n number of columns. What would be the most efficient way of doing it.

Comment: For an arbitrary number of columns, you will need some dynamic SQL.

Comment: You can use `PIVOT`. Ref: https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
sqlqry clob;
cols clob;
begin
 select String_agg('''' || id || ''' as "' || id || '"', ',') 
 into   cols
 from   (select distinct id from your_table);


 sqlqry :=
  '      
  select * from
 (
  select *
  from your_table
 )
 pivot
(
max(name) for id in (' || cols  || ')
 )';

execute immediate sqlqry;
end;
/
```

Comment: Why are you using `string_agg()` instead of `listagg()`?

Comment: string_agg don't need any group to aggregate within(unlike listagg) so used string_agg

Comment: @kirangadhe string_agg isn't an Oracle provided procedure though.

Comment: It is clearly mentioned in the link that it's a UDF. You should specify it as a user defined function and add the link/code to your answer. .